# Objective c iOS passing data

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsstring

hi I am new to iOS and below is my code I have to pass the top that I get from request reply...please help me I am stuck here
first view controller is otp view second vc is verifyviewcontroller

Otp view c.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface OtpViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *str;
@end
```

otpviewcontroller.m

```
#import "OtpViewController.h"
#import "VerifyViewController.h"
@interface OtpViewController () <VerifyViewControllerDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *bbi;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *submittf;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *mobiletf;
@property (weak,nonatomic) NSArray *tmp;
@property(weak,nonatomic) NSString *requestReply ;
//@property(weak,nonatomic) NSDictionary *A;
@end

@implementation OtpViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]];
NSLog(@"viewDidLoad");
[super viewDidLoad];

}

- (IBAction)submitb:(id)sender
 {

if (_mobiletf.text && _mobiletf.text.length >0 )
{
    /* not empty - do something */
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"phone=%@",_mobiletf.text];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    //  Next up, we read the postData's length, so we can pass it along in the request.

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
    // Now that we have what we'd like to post, we can create an NSMutableURLRequest, and include our postData.

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.sitesandflats.com/send_otp.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    NSLog(@"the data Details is %@", post);

    //   And finally, we can send our request, and read the reply by creating a new NSURLSession:

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);
        NSString *str=requestReply;
        VerifyViewController *vc = [[VerifyViewController alloc] init];
        NSString  *tmp=requestReply;
        NSLog(@"%@",str);
        NSLog(@"%@",_tmp);

    }] resume];
    [ self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"b1" sender:self];
   }
else
{
    /* what ever */
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
        message:@"Please check your input!!."
        delegate:self
        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
        otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}


}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(nullable id)sender{

VerifyViewController *loadCtr = (VerifyViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
loadCtr.delegate = self;
loadCtr.tmpStr = (@"otp: %@",_tmp);
NSLog(@"passing val: %@",_tmp);
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return YES;
}
```

Verify view controller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol VerifyViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)moveToA:(NSString *)str;
@end
@interface VerifyViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *tmpStr;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <VerifyViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
//@property (nonatomic, strong) OtpViewController *received;
//@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textDisplay;
@property(nonatomic,weak) NSMutableArray *myAray;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *object;
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSString *tmp1;
@end
```

Verify view controller.m

```
#import "VerifyViewController.h"
#import "OtpViewController.h"
@interface VerifyViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *otptf;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *submitb;
//@property (weak,nonatomic) textDisplay;
//@property (weak,nonatomic) NSString  *received;
@end


@implementation VerifyViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage     imageNamed:@"background"]];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
- (IBAction)submitb:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"%@",_tmpStr); 
if(_otptf.text==_tmpStr)
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"b2" sender:self];
}
else{

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                    message:@"Incorrect otp please check the input!!!."
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

}


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

at nslog I get reply as ("success":"1";"otp":"985123") I need this otp to store and verify in next page please help

Comment: You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers) link helpfull.

Comment: 2017-05-31 12:10:12.540 MenuBar[1315:76259] the data Details is phone=9047038606
2017-05-31 12:10:12.554 MenuBar[1315:76259] passing val: (null)
2017-05-31 12:10:13.267 MenuBar[1315:76307] requestReply: {"success":1,"otp":"118301"}
2017-05-31 12:10:13.268 MenuBar[1315:76307] {"success":1,"otp":"118301"}
2017-05-31 12:10:13.269 MenuBar[1315:76307] {"success":1,"otp":"118301"}

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban I have checked it but the answers were passing bool values

Comment: can you explain  what you want to do  ?

Comment: **I need this top to store** can correct this ? top or otp ?

Comment: @akshay you can pass values of any type.

Comment: @KKRocks ya typo its otp

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban thanks I will try and see!!!

Comment: @akshay good luck then

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban thanks;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to change property

**From**

```
@property (weak,nonatomic) NSArray *tmp;
```

**To**

```
 @property (strong,nonatomic) NSStirng *tmp;
```

Assign value to **tmp** as below

```
[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
           NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; // this is json string
           NSError *error;
           NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error]; // you need to convert to dictionary object

            NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", jsonDict);
            self.tmp=[jsonDict valueForKey:@"otp"] ; // you need to extract value using the key   [requestReply valueForKey:@"otp"];
            NSLog(@"%@",self.tmp);

    }] resume];
```

**Pass tmp to VerifyVIewController**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(nullable id)sender{

VerifyViewController *loadCtr = (VerifyViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
loadCtr.delegate = self;
loadCtr.tmpStr = self.tmp;
NSLog(@"passing val: %@",_tmp);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your effort!!bt stilll I get passing values null at log

Comment: 2017-05-31 12:43:32.741 MenuBar[1398:90037] passing val: (null)
2017-05-31 12:43:33.464 MenuBar[1398:90096] requestReply:{"success":1,"otp":"753161"}
2017-05-31 12:43:33.464 MenuBar[1398:90096] {"success":1,"otp":"753161"}

Comment: you need to extract value .

Comment: self.tmp = [requestReply valueForKey:@"otp"];

Comment: 2017-05-31 12:51:08.063 MenuBar[1435:93502] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x60800024eeb0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key otp.'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: the app crashes

Comment: wait i update my answer because it is the json string and you need to extract that.

Comment: I am getting the extracted value but the value is not passing to not vc

Comment: what happens did you print while you have segue?

Comment: ya I have printed In prepare for segue method and passing value is still (null)....dnt understand it:(

Comment: you can declare tmpStr as strong instead of copy and check it once

Comment: @RajeshDharani Thanks . might be this is the issue .

Comment: @RajeshDharani I checked it and ran the code still its showing null is there any other prob??

Comment: I have a doubt will it execute code even after moving to next page coz I have moved at the end of extracting  top from json??@KKRocks @RajeshDharani

Comment: Try this way may be its works I'm not tested  Click on VerifyViewController  xib file or if its in storyboard, remove all earlier bindings And Add new binding by providing IBOutlets,Clean project and run again.

Comment: did you check that it is passed to verifyController ?

Comment: 2017-05-31 15:14:08.219 MenuBar[1876:138678] the data Details is phone=9047038606. 
                                                                                                                    2017-05-31 15:14:13.588 MenuBar[1876:138678] passed val: (null).
2017-05-31 15:14:21.172 MenuBar[1876:139004] requestReply: {
    otp = 453389;
    success = 1;
}
2017-05-31 15:15:16.412 MenuBar[1876:139004] 453389
2017-05-31 15:15:25.896 MenuBar[1876:139004] requestReply: {
    otp = 453389;
    success = 1;
}
2017-05-31 15:15:25.897 MenuBar[1876:139004] tmp storage:45338

Comment: why is my passed value coming first before even storing the value??@KKRocks

Comment: where you written this **passed val**.

Comment: in prepare for segue method I have given nslog for passing value and no it gives only null!!I jus changed the passing value to passed value to know the difference!!

Comment: did you use tmp string anywhere else in this class ?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",self.tmp);
 is this print object ?

Comment: that works for other statements bt for this it shows null

Comment: then you made some mistake for access that property .